# How to break a line in .kv file?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

No matter what I have tried so far if I try to break the line

> "Process finished with exit code 1 "

```
  Button:
        id: camera_btn
        text: 'Play'
        on_press: root.start() if root.ids.camera.play == False else root.stop()
```

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific and show us which line? Also if you can, I'd love you to also tell us what you are trying to do. And btw it would be great if you can provide us [a minimal and reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change your code like this.
Please try it and let me know if it works

```
on_press: 
    root.start() 
    if root.ids.camera.play == True: \ 
    root.stop();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).